# Why toggleClass is not executed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a little trouble when I use *.toggleClass* in my code. Sometimes, it works, sometimes not. I have read many posts about it but none have helped me.

Can you help me, please?

jQuery

```
var e = $(".pwdMask > .form-control"),
  t = $(".pwd-toggle");

$(t).on("click", function(t) {
  t.preventDefault(),
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash"),
    $(this).hasClass("fa-eye") ? $(e).attr("type", "text") : $(e).attr("type", "password")
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="pwdMask">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="_password" placeholder="(...)" }}">
   <span class="focus-input"></span>
   <span class="fas pwd-toggle fa-eye fa-eye-slash"></span>
</div>
```

I call jQuery, Bootstrap.js and my custom.js files at the end of the HTML page.

I already thank you!

Comment: Here you are but with jsfiddle, it works... [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dunhy18w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The problem was that I had 2 times each scripts because I closed the TWIG tag wrongly.

If it happens to somebody one day, don't forget to close `body blocks` before using `javascript blocks`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove one class your HTML

```
<span class="fas pwd-toggle fa-eye-slash"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/2uwcda5b/3/

Comment: Ho, I forgot to delete it yesterday but it still doesn't work.. I think about a js conflict but can't find it.